# How to get an input text value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How go get an input text value in JavaScript?

I want to get input text value in jquery script but it prompted empty.

my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var emails;
    function checkRegistration() {
        emails = document.getElementById('my_email').value;
        alert(emails);
    }
</script>
```

my form code :

```
<form method="post" role="form" onSubmit="return checkRegistration()" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="my_email" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Forgot Password" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery

Comment: I don't find any issues with your code, it runs fine.And to answer your title `$('#my_email').val();`

Comment: @SanKrish https://jsfiddle.net/yo7k586b/1/ *does not work*. It returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkRegistration is not defined"

Comment: And here it in jsbin https://jsbin.com/mifehanala/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Interesting @SanKrish - I wonder what the differences are?

Comment: Are you getting an empty `alert()`?

Comment: The difference is `jsfiddle` doesnt wrap through the code unless you explicitly mention it . You can try running the code as HTML document it will prompt the desired value

Answer (score 1):

First check are you using `jquery.min.js` file or not.

Second if you want to get value using `id`. `id` should be unique on that page.

Try below

```
var my_email= $('#my_email').val();
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Why does it matter if the OP is "*using jquery min file or not*"? Minified or not minified won't make a difference to the answer.

Comment: @Rajender It doesnt answer the op's question , read the complete question . As your answer only solves his title

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Add `required` attribute to `input type="email"` element, to prevent form submission if value not entered by user

---

Use `.onchange` event

```js
var emails = document.getElementById("my_email");

function checkRegistration() {
  alert(this.value);
}

emails.onchange = checkRegistration;
```

```html
<form method="post" role="form" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="my_email" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Forgot Password" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The OP is using a submit event, so why use the `onchange()`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Does `submit` event of `form` element with `action` attribute set to `#` reload page ?

Comment: It does, but it will still throw the alert prior to the page reloading.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If user submits form before entering values the alert would be empty string. This is why used `onchange` event at Answer above. Perhaps solution is to add `required` attribute to `input type="email"` element ?

Comment: Given that the OP says "it prompted empty" you may be right.